# Dynamodb reading and writing units

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've been reading various articles on the Amazon DynamoDB but I'm still a little confused on the reading/writing units on how these are used. For example, using the free version, I have 5 writing units and 10 reading units available per second, each unit representing  1kb of data. But what does this really mean?

Does this mean max 10 read requests can be performed per seconds or max 10kb of data can be requested per seconds(regardless of whether there are 10 or 100 requests)? Because this aspect is not clear for me. So if I have 20 users who concurrently access a page on my website(which result in 20 queries being performed to retrieve data), what will happen? Will 10 of them see the the data immediately while the other 10 will see it after 1 second? Or will they all see the data immediately if the data requested (multiplied by 20) is less then 10kb?

Also, if the reading units are not enough, and 100 users request concurrently 1kb of data each, does this mean all the requests will require 10 seconds to complete??

Also, the pricing is a little confusing as I don't understand if the prices are paid for units reserved or consumed? So for example they say the price is "Write Throughput: $0.00735 per hour for every 10 units of Write Capacity". Does this mean one will pay ($0.00735*24=$0.176) even if no writing requests are made during a day?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are correct in that the capacity is tightly bound to the size of the objects being read/written.

### Feb 2016 Updates

AWS has updated how they calculate throughput, and the they've increased from 1 KB objects to 4 KB for their calculations. The discussion below is still valid, but certain calculations are different now.

Always consult the latest DynamoDB documentation for the latest information and examples on how to calculate throughput.

### Older Documentation

From the AWS DynamoDB documentation (as of 1/8/14):

> Units of Capacity required for writes = Number of item writes per
>   second x item size (rounded up to the nearest KB)
>
> Units of Capacity required for reads* = Number of item reads per
>   second x item size (rounded up to the nearest KB)
>
> - If you use eventually consistent reads you’ll get twice the throughput in terms of reads per second.

Per your example question, if you want to read 10KB of data per second you'll need 10 Read Units provisioned. It doesn't matter if you make 10 requests for 1 KB of data or if you make a single request for 10 KB of data. You're limited to 10KB/second.

> Note that the required number of units of Read Capacity is determined
>   by the number of items being read per second, not the number of API
>   calls. For example, if you need to read 500 items per second from your
>   table, and if your items are 1KB or less, then you need 500 units of
>   Read Capacity. **It doesn’t matter if you do 500 individual GetItem
>   calls or 50 BatchGetItem calls that each return 10 items.**

For your 20 user example, keep in mind that data is rounded up to the nearest KB. So even if your 20 users request 0.5 KB of data, you'll need 20 Read Units to service all of them at once. If you only have 10 read units, then the other 10 requests will be throttled. If you use the Amazon DynamoDB libraries, they have auto-retry logic baked in to try the request again so they should eventually get serviced.

For your question about 100 users, some of those requests may simply be throttled and the retry logic may eventually fail (the code will only retry the request so many times before it stops trying) - so you need to be ready to handle those 400 response codes from DynamoDB and react accordingly. **It's very important to monitor your application when you use DynamoDB and ensure you aren't going to be throttled on app critical transactions.**

Your last question about pricing - you pay hourly for what you reserve. If you reserve 1000 Read Units and your site has absolutely no traffic, then too bad, you'll still pay hourly for those 1000 Read Units.

For completeness - keep in mind that throughput is provision PER TABLE. So if you have 3 DynamoDB tables: Users, Photos, Friends then you have to provision capacity for each table, and you need to determine what is appropriate for each table. In this trivial example, perhaps Photos is accessed less frequently in your app so you can provision lower throughput compared to your Users table.

Eventually consistent reads are great for cost saving but your app has to be designed to handle it. An eventually consistent read means that if you update data and immediately try to read the new value, you may not get the new value back, it may still return the previous value. Eventually, with enough time, you'll get the new value. You pay less since you aren't guaranteed to read the latest data - but that can be OK if you design appropriately.

Comment: Still not clear on the request number limitation. Aurel on his answer says the number of requests isn't relevant but you say that data is rounded to the nearest kb. So I'm correct in assuming that a read unit will always support maximum 1 request. Because event if the request only returns one item with a small string(which is irrelevant in size), the data is rounded to 1 kb so it will consume 1 read unit. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct - 1 read unit will only ever get you 1 item. You can double this if you use eventually consistent reads.

Comment: You've said that it doesn't matter if we get 500 individual GetItem calls or 50 BatchGetItem calls that each return 10 items. But according to this doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughputIntro.html#ProvisionedThroughputIntro.Reads  it is said that if we use Query it takes only the considers the **cumulative size of the processed items**

Comment: @user7 That sentence was copied from the AWS documentation from 1/8/2014. They've made some great updates since that time.

Comment: Say I have a query that'll fetch 3000 records and each record is 1KB. So the cumulative size is 3000 KB. Should the throughput be 3000/4=750? Does it have to be this high? I guess the query results are not going to be retrieved in one second, so we can have a lower throughput.

Comment: Regarding the 'Feb 2016 Update' in this answer, the 4KB increase is only for read units. Write units still use the 1KB limit. See FAQ: http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#What_is_a_readwrite_capacity_unit

Answer (score 5):

Think of it as a pipe diameter : you pay for a possible data throughput per second. The number of requests isn't relevant.

Besides, if you ask for 10 read units, then you will indeed pay for 10 units, regardless of your actual traffic.

If your traffic were to raise above the limit, you would first get a warning ( let's say at 80% of your provisionned troughput). Then the requests begin to take more time. If you are still above the limit for a significant amount of time, new connections can be refused for a few minutes.

Hope that helps

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, if you have a job that runs on an interval, when that job starts it needs to write say 100 records, then it sleeps for another 5 min, then writes again. You would need to provision enough Write Capacity to support that burst of activity, it's not averaged over the day.

Comment: You're right. Now perhaps aws isn't so strict so it could work anyways for small burst. Perhaps also you should double check the rules, since this was written in 2014 :)

Answer (score 1):

•   Adding and updating items consume your write throughput and requesting/querying items consume your read throughput in dynamo db. The maximum size for a single item in a DynamoDB table is 400 kb, the bigger your items are, the more throughput you consume and more your cost will be. If you are searching in DynamoDB using key then table scan will not happen and you need throughput equivalent to your item size, for example if your item size is 4kb then you need 1 read capacity units(1 unit is equivalent  to 4KB/seconds),  if you want to read 40KB of data per second you'll need 10 Read Units provisioned. It doesn't matter if you make 10 requests for 4 KB of data or if you make a single request for 40 KB of data. You're limited to 40KB/second. But if you are searching apart from key then DynamoDB scans the complete data from table, while scanning db will cross provisioned throughput limit when data is high in database, We can increase the throughput of table to maximum value needed while scanning but that will increase the cost and will make out database sitting completely idle most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article, all details are there:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html#ItemSizeCalculations.Reads

In general, you pay for each item, where each item size is rounded to the next 1KB/4KB for Write/Read operations.

The only exception for this rule is when you do a query / scan calls:

> All items returned are treated as a single read operation, where DynamoDB computes the total size of all items and then rounds up to the next 4 KB boundary. If a query returns 1500 items of 64 bytes each, the cumulative size is 96 KB.