# AWS for chat is it worth it in the end?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chat, amazon-dynamodb

Was wondering how easily a DynamoDB chat can be scalable on AWS as of now (Nov 2016) for iPhone App?

Would it be enough for let's say 1000 simultaneous users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS DynamoDB is a fast and flexible NoSQL database service for all applications that need consistent, single-digit millisecond latency at any scale.

So, I think DynamoDB will be scalable but what you need to consider is the Pricing factor.

DynamoDb pricing is little confusing. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999465/dynamodb-reading-and-writing-units) for DynamoDB price calculation. If you want a cost efficient approach, then you should be careful in choosing the **RCU** and **WCU** for your dynamoDB table.

Comment: Thank you,  what do you think RCU and WCU should be?